# Using STL within omnetpp

Tags: c++, omnet++

I want to use `set` in C++ Standard Template Library (STL)
I have already included the `set` and `iterator` library normally inside my `.cc` file.

but I get this error message

```sh
make MODE=release all 
diffuse_v3.cc
In file included from diffuse_v3.cc:11:0:
Snail_m.h:43:5: error: ‘set’ does not name a type
     set <int, greater<int> > s1;
     ^
Makefile:103: recipe for target 'out/gcc-release//diffuse_v3.o' failed
make: *** [out/gcc-release//diffuse_v3.o] Error 1
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Tip: The STL is long dead. It's the *Standard Library* now, or STandard Library if you're clinging to the old name.

Comment: What source generated this error? This should not be an issue if a) `#include <set>` was used, and b) you're `using namespace std` even though that's a bad habit to get into. If not (b) then `std::set` is the way to refer to it.

Comment: I still have  the same issue ever when I use `std::set`

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide [mre]? At least the code that causes an error.

Comment: That is how it's supposed to be used, so if you have problems you need to show us some minimal code that generates the error, plus give us some information on the version of GCC involved. If it's really old the first thing I'd do is upgrade if you can.

Comment: here a diffuse_v3.cc source code and my gcc version

Comment: https://gist.github.com/151ali/3ac3e57960791fd7d6ff8abca44d1a52

Comment: Actually, your error log shows that the problem is in `Snail_m.h`. Could you edit your question and add `Snail.msg`?

Comment: this is the full source codes https://github.com/151ali/diffuse_v

Comment: After changing `greater<int>` into `std::greater<int>` in `diffuse_v3.cc` that project compiles without errors.